# Add visual effect if two users with same name comment on same post

Tags: feature-request, comments, comment-replies

With such a common first name this had to happen one day or another:

[image]

Some comments are from [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/637853/thomas) and some others are from myself.

If I was OP (or any other person) I would get my mind blown and loose a lot of time hovering each comment to see which one is talking about what.

It would be nice to add some light visual effect to ease the user distinguish different users.

Side question: how does ping works if it's done from a third person?

Comment: In the general case, it should not matter who is leaving the comments. The information they provide should stand alone. That seems to be true here (aside from the ensuing off-topic discussion).

Comment: As for your last part of this question, that's been asked before- The ping will go to the _last_ of the users with the same name who commented. Edit: That's covered [in the MSE faq.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) _"Matching is performed in reverse chronological order, so if five people named John are participating, @john will match the most recent John._"

Comment: Have you considered solving this problem yourself?  Make your username a bit more unique.

Comment: The perfect time to become Thomas Edison :)

Comment: Or perhaps "TheTaGuy".

Comment: @CodyGray yes, but then we might remove the names from the comments fully :-) The way it is (for an Alex), it can be very confusing. Not sure if adding a miniature Avatar would help.